# Color of placeholder text in an input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an input field which has a placeholder text. I want one word to be a different color say red, how would would I go about that? Styling a span and surrounding the word with the span didn't work.

For example on this site, I want to the number in the phrase "Search 649 radio stories" to be red.

http://66.251.226.207/library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about overlaying a div over the input that disappears when you click it (and then directs focus to the input)? That way you can style the portions of text however you want.

```
$('#myInputOverlayDiv').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#myInputElement').focus();
})
```

Answer (score 10):

*I can't tell about a single word, but if you were to style the whole placeholder, then read this.*

Since placeholders are only supported by WebKit so far, you can use the following [css rule](http://trac.webkit.org/export/37527/trunk/LayoutTests/fast/forms/placeholder-pseudo-style.html) for it:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

For other browsers, as support for placeholder attribute evolves, you'll have to use different rules. For Gecko-based browsers you may want to watch Mozilla's [bug 457801](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457801) to find out what the final solution will be.